# MySQL Query displayed in HTML tags problem

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm working on this little website project, nothing serious, more like fun project
I have this mySQL database to keep posts in it

```
CREATE TABLE commentsy(
    comment_id int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    comment_author varchar(128) not null,
    comment_date datetime not null,
    comment_text TEXT not null,
    comment_photo_id TEXT not null
);
```

and on my homepage i'd like to dispaly post that goes under id #1

```
<?php

$conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','wpisy');

if(!$conn){
    die(" error: ".mysqli_connect_error());

}


$sql = "SELECT  `comment_date`, `comment_text`, `comment_photo_id`, 'comment_title' FROM `commentsy` WHERE `comment_id` = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo"<div class='card'>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $title = $row['comment_title'];
        $date = $row['comment_date'];
        $text = $row['comment_text'];
        $pid = $row['comment_photo_id'];




        echo $row['comment_title'];
        echo"<h2>" .$title  ;
        echo"</h2>";
        echo"<div class='Image-Thumbnail'>";
        echo"<img src=./img/$pid height=50% width=50%>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<p>";
        echo".$text";
        echo"</p>";
        echo"<div class=toTheRight>" .$date ;
        echo"</div>";




    }
echo"</div>";

    }
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

and the problem is - instead of title being displayed properly it dispalys `comment_title` on both lines, in h2 tags and line above.

any ideas / suggestions what am i doing wrong here ?
All the other stuff works like a charm.

Comment: "any ideas" - Yes.. You are looking in the wrong database. Or the page is cached. Or you are executing the wrong script.

Comment: " All the other stuff works like a charm." - Can you see this `echo"<div class=toTheRight>" .$date ;` printed somewhere?

Comment: am I ? there's screenshot of my db below, decided to get rid of the author bit tho.
And yes, its printed below picture.

Comment: @bartbart I am having difficulty understanding what results you're after. It's normal behaviour for an `<H>` tag to be on its own line with whatever is being echo'd above and below. If you want things on one line, then include what you want echo'd inside the `<H>` tag. This is HTML 101. I am also tempted to convert my comment to an answer. You might even have an CSS rule somewhere making it much larger than usual. You're also echoing out the same row.

Comment: https://imgur.com/uWhdUWh
instead of echoing what ever is in my comment_title in database, my website prints out literally "comment_title ", also i know its doubled, did that on purpose

Comment: Ok I see what the issue is now after going over your code again. Remove the quotes for this `'comment_title'` in the query or use ticks as you did for the other ones. Having used `mysqli_error($conn)` would have thrown an error about it. @bartbart Consult the duplicates.